# how to replace blank data from webscrape with something else?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

```
layovers = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@data-test-id='layover-airport-stops']")
layovers_list = [value.text for value in layovers]
```

To **scrape** data from the web, i have used the code above.

```
    try:
        df.loc[i, 'layovers'] = layovers_list[i]
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

However, the first few data are blank/zero , so python automatically pulls the data from other flights that have non-zero/ non-blank layovers to the match with first few data, which results in wrong match because the first few flights have no layovers. I was thinking of making the blank data 0.
1)As im not too familiar with HTML, may i know if there is a way to edit the data?

2)May I know what is the type of data (eg.string, list) in `browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@data-test-id='layover-airport-stops']")` ? It will be useful to know because I would like to slice the data for other purposes. eg. i wanted to do this but i couldnt
`airport_list=[] for value in airport: airport_list.append(value[1:3]) return airport_list`

Comment: How is the blank data detected? Couldn't you check for an empty string? Or is it stored as `None`?

Comment: what i meant by BLANK DATA was that it does not even have @data-test-id='layover-airport-stops' in the HTML on the webpage. that is why the first row of layovers list is NOT the first flight.

Comment: Okay. Perhaps it is injected dynamically? Wouldn't surprise me in the age of Single Page Applications.
Selenium offers options to wait for a selector to show up.